# How to show/hide content using react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile-development

How to create dropdown menu using react-native?

How to show/hide content?

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you have tried thus far? You ask how to create a dropdown and how to show/hide content... is the showing and hiding meant to try and create a dropdown or are these two independent questions?

Comment: For example I need dropdown like this http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-single

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/alinz/react-native-dropdown

This will give you the dropdown similar to what you asked for. Showing/Hiding of content is simply making the decision to render or not the content which can be done in a multitude of ways.

```
render() {
    let hideableContent;

    if (this.state.shouldRenderContent) {
        hideableContent = <Text>I AM SHOWING</Text>;
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>This doesn't hide</Text>
            {hideableContent}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: I like the less verbose version of this: `{this.state.shouldRenderContent && (<Text>I AM SHOWING</Text>)}`.

Comment: Yes, that way works as well. There are tons of ways to do it and I doubt most of them would bring performance concerns so it all boils down to team (or personal if there is just you) preference.